# Loading listview using SharedPreferences throwing OutofMemoryError

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, sharedpreferences

I am using edittext and button in mainactivity, onclicking I want to add the text to listview which it does properly.

I am also saving it using sharedpreferences,so that when I go back to mainactivity or restart app ,it automatically loads listview,but on clicking button ,I get OutOfMemoryerror at this line:

```
   arrayCars.add(new Car(pred.getString("Value["+i+"]", ""),"green",3455));
```

Listview code:

```
       ArrayList<Car> arrayCars;
ListView listViewCars;
String venName;
SharedPreferences pred;
SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor;
static int count = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    arrayCars=new ArrayList<Car>();

    System.out.println("count is"+count);
    pred = getSharedPreferences("place", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       spEditor = pred.edit();
       count = pred.getInt("countd",count);
        if(count > 0){
           for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){

               arrayCars.add(new Car(pred.getString("Value["+i+"]",  ""),"green",3455));


        count++;
           }
          }

      listViewCars = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_cars);
    ListCarsAdapter adapter = new ListCarsAdapter(this, arrayCars);
    listViewCars.setAdapter(adapter);
    listViewCars.setOnItemClickListener(this);



    try{
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
         venName = bundle.getString("r"); 
    }catch(Exception e){}

        if(venName!=null){
        spEditor.putString("Value["+count+"]", venName);
        spEditor.apply();
        arrayCars.add(new Car(pred.getString("Value["+count+"]", ""),"red",3444));
        count += 1;
        spEditor.putInt("countd", count);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }  

    }
```

PS: I am using custom listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
count = pred.getInt("countd",count);
    if(count > 0){
       for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){

           arrayCars.add(new Car(pred.getString("Value["+i+"]",  ""),"green",3455));


    count++;
       }
    }
```

In the above code you are increasing count by 1 each time so it never ends loop will repeat untill it throw exception.

To avoid delete that count++;

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

delete the  `count++;` you increasing the count variable while increasing the i, so the for loop will never stop